В браузере при загрузке фотографии у пользователей всплывает ошибка: "Не удалось завершить операцию (недостаточно памяти)"
Создал веб-приложение на Angular 17 для загрузки пользователями фотографий с камеры телефона. У пользователей с Android часто возникает ошибка "Не удалось завершить операцию (недостаточно памяти)" (см. Скриншот). Временно помогает ошибка кэша, но это не панацея и непонятно, почему она возникает на новых, мощных устройствах. Изображения мы сжимаем до 200Кб, на вход они поступают не больше 7Мб. Как решить проблему капитально? Что бы пользователи что-то поменяли в настройках или нам как-то пометить, что файл в кэше хранить не надо? 
Логика загрузки изображений:
HTML:
<mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button class="button" *ngIf="isContractors" (click)="openCameraAfter()"> 
    Прикрепить
    </button>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" 
        (change)="onFileSelected($event, true)" #fileInputAfter style="display: none">
</mat-card-actions>

TS:
onFileSelected(event: any, flag: boolean) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const base64result = reader.result as string;
        this.takeExifData(base64result, flag, 0)
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

